# How can I find out what is using NTLM in my environment?

Tags: windows, active-directory, ntlm

I have seen Event Logs in Windows Event Viewer with EventID 6038 from Source LsaSrv.

My systems are: SQL server 2019 and Windows 10 20H2 machines.

I am attempting to audit what is using NTLM Authentication but do not know how to do this within Windows 10 or Windows Server.

[image: EventID 6038]

Comment: You should enable audit for NTLM on the ADC https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/security/threat-protection/security-policy-settings/network-security-restrict-ntlm-audit-ntlm-authentication-in-this-domain and https://serverfault.com/questions/887969/auditing-ntlm-authentication-on-domain-controllers-which-gpo

Comment: Ahh the gpo should allow me to see the app using it in the event logs or at least the CLSID ~ Thank you Hardoman I will test this

Comment: Not the app but user and accounts trying to authenticate. From this you can find out the app using them.